# Automatic CSS versioning in PHP?

Tags: php, css, versioning

How can I achieve such a versioning system in PHP?

```
<link href="/assets/ver_e139fafc4ba724c15e947555e00fca64/css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Found this on quote.fm.

Comment: Define automatic CSS versioing. It can mean more than one thing.

Comment: I find the question to be completely unclear. Please specify better.

Comment: It seems that they use a automatic folder-system which writes subfolders depending on the version of their software. I would like to know how I can achieve this. Hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to just append a ? and the css file's modified time.